# AWS Cloudformation Stringlist error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation

**ERROR:** Property validation failure: [Value of property {/StreamingDistributionConfig/TrustedSigners/AwsAccountNumbers} does not match type {Array}].

I am trying to get multiple account Id's in a parameter called awsAccountNumbers, for which the cloudformation document says this parameter must be of type StringList. However, there's no such type. We have **String** and **CommaDelimitedList** in the AWS parameters reference for which I get the mentioned error. I tried splitting it too, but of no help. Please find my code below:

```
**Parameters Section:** 
  "awsAccountNumbers": {
            "Type": "String",

  }

**Resources Section:** 

   "TrustedSigners": {
                        "AwsAccountNumbers": {
                            "Fn::If": [
                                "withRestrictViewerAccessasYes",
                                {
                                    "Fn::If": [
                                        "withTrustedSignersasSelf",
                                        "882410330966",
                                        [
                                            {
                                                "Fn::Select": [
                                                    "0",
                                                    {
                                                        "Fn::Split": [
                                                            ",",

                                                            { "Ref": "awsAccountNumbers" }

                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "Enabled": {
                            "Ref": "trustedSignersEnabled"
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the error points to the actual properties([AwsAccountNumbers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-streamingdistribution-trustedsigners.html#cfn-cloudfront-streamingdistribution-trustedsigners-awsaccountnumbers)) not the parameter(awsAccountNumbers).

[AwsAccountNumbers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-streamingdistribution-trustedsigners.html#cfn-cloudfront-streamingdistribution-trustedsigners-awsaccountnumbers) expects a list. It should be something like below (untested)

```
"Parameters" : {
  "awsAccountNumbers": {
    "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
     "Default": "882410330966, 882410330966, 882410330966"
  }

{
    "TrustedSigners": {
        "AwsAccountNumbers": [{
            "Fn::If": [
                "withRestrictViewerAccessasYes",
                {
                    "Fn::If": [
                        "withTrustedSignersasSelf",
                        "882410330966", [{
                            "Fn::Select": [
                                "0",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "awsAccountNumbers"
                                }
                            ]
                        }]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
                }
            ]
        }],
        "Enabled": {
            "Ref": "trustedSignersEnabled"
        }
    }
}
```